# Xlwings mac office 2016 - Not a directory error

Tags: xlwings

When I try to run an excel workbook in office 2016, i get the following error message:

```
sh: /usr/local/bin/python3.4/python: Not a directory
```

It work's in 2011 - what is wrong? Please see details below:

xlwings: 0.7,
Office: 2016,
OS: Mac,
PYTHON_MAC = "/usr/local/bin/python3.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently a bug really, as `PYTHON_MAC` should accept the path *including* the interpreter instead of the path only, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/289).

**Update**: This has been fixed with the release of v0.7.1

Comment: Looking very much forward to the fix - keep up the good work :)

Comment: @DauleDK I hope to include the fix in v0.7.1. As a temporary workaround, you could create a virtualenv and point to the interpreter there...